# Correct use of smash with math and root signs

Tags: equations

How can I get the same height on the second root-sign as the first?;

```
$$\sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{16a^2}}
=\sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{(4a)^2}}$$
```

I've tried different methods using `\smash`, `\vphantom` and `\rule[]{}{}` but could not work out which was the best and most 'proper' way of solving this 'problem'. TIA.

Comment: Thanks for all help, but I cannot understand why the ^2 cannot go under the `\smash` command in the solution suggested by Mico. The following two examples does not result in the same display: `\smash{(4a)}^2` and `\smash{(4a)^2}` (Sorry, did not know how to type in the comment box to get better display of codes.)

Comment: If you compare the outputs of `\smash{(4a)}^2` and `\smash{(4a)^2}`, you'll notice that the exponent is placed higher relative to the baseline if the scope of `\smash` includes the exponent -- not by a huge amount, for sure, but by about 1 or 2 points. This difference results in a slight increase in the overall height of the denominator which, in turn, explains why LaTeX sees fit to employ a taller (and deeper) square root symbol when it processes `\smash{(4a)^2}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is replace `(4a)^2` in the second denominator with either `\smash{(4a)}^2` or `\smash[b]{(4a)}^2`. This yields compact-looking square root terms, and it works with both `\tfrac` and `\dfrac`.

Observe that if you, alternatively, replaced `16a^2` in the first denominator with `16a^2\mathstrut`, the two square root symbols would also have equal sizes. However, they would be much taller -- excessively and unnecessarily so, IMNSHO -- than with the adjustment suggested above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[
 \sqrt{\dfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{16a^2}}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\smash{(4a)}^2}}
\]

\[
 \sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{16a^2}}
=\sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\smash{(4a)}^2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see comment in the question, I might have put it in the wrong place… Perhaps it should have been here.

Comment: @mf67 - Please see the comment I left below your follow-up comment. Did I answer your question? Please advise.

Comment: I don't fully understand the effect of `\smash` it seems. I thought that `\smash{(4a)^2}` would remove any height and 'equal' it to, e.g. an "a" or "x" and thus not extend the root sign any deeper. Instead it seems like it, as you write, places the exponent higher, but normal, than in `\smash{(4a)}^2` and thus forces down the base and therefore the depth of the root sign. A 0-height box, as I thought `\smash{(4a)^2}` was, would not do that? The `\smash{(4a)}^2` 'compress' the exponent and, although not extremely disturbingly 'ugly', it looks a bit different from the `a^2` in the numerator.

Comment: @mf67 - I don't thinks it's entirely correct to call `\smash{(4a)^2}` a  "zero-height box". Please compile `\[ \sqrt{\frac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\smash{(4a)}^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\smash{(4a)^2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\smash{\smash{(4a)^2}}}} \]`. You'll see that the square root term in the middle, which contains `\smash{(4a)^2}`, is taller than the other two. It looks like it's necessary to `\smash` the term `(4a)^2` *twice* in order to obtain the compact square root expression shown on the left. That's why I recommended writing `\smash{(4a)}^2`...

Comment: @mf67 - If this topic continues to puzzle you, may I suggest that you post a *new query,* in which you would ask for an explanation of how exactly `\smash` works? There are some amazing TeX wizards on this site; they can explain how `\smash` works in all gory detail -- and much much better than I ever could.

Answer (score 10):

Equalizing radicals is something of a black art.

The difference is due to the right hand side having parentheses. We can cope with this by adding `\mathstrut` in the left hand side denominator. But this makes TeX choose the next size for the radical. Using `\smash[b]{...}` for the denominator doesn't help.

The problem is that `\tfrac` imposes `\textstyle`, which has raised denominators. One could use `\cramped` from `mathtools`, but there's a slicker solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\textstyle
\sqrt{\frac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\mathstrut 16a^2}}
=\sqrt{\frac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{(4a)^2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simple `\vphantom` will do the trick. And, please, don't use the plain TeX construct `$$ ... $$` for unnumbered displayed equations. Use `[ ... \]` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{\vphantom{)}16a^2}} =\sqrt{\tfrac{1+2\cdot4a^2+(4a^2)^2}{(4a)^2}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]